# Taking a 360 image

Tags: android, 360-degrees, 360-virtual-reality

I want to make an app in android with android studio. In this app I want to take 360 picture but unfortunately I cannot find any material according to taking picture in 360'.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @ahsan you can still limit the question to a specific problem. Add details of what you have tried and what you want to achieve. have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask